# Have a command within a batch wait to run

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script and of the many commands, etc, here's one that I need help with:

```
findstr /i /v /%HomeDrive%"Registered Owner" %HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Document\FOLDERNAMEHERE\systeminfo1.txt >%HomeDrive%\%HomePath%\Documents\FOLDERNAMEHERE\systeminfo.txt
```

Essentially what this does for me is it removes the **Registered Owner** field from a sysinfo log, and then dumps the newly created sysinfo log without **Registered Owner**. My problem is that given this is a batch script, it's going too fast and it does not allow enough time for any of the information to be written to the second .txt log. It's created with 0KB's and is blank.

I've tried implementing a line after the above code:

```
timeout /t 15 /nobreak >NUL
```

However, this does me no good as it does it **after** the above code is run, not while.

Can anyone please inform me how to give the file time to be written to, so the batch just doesn't go right to the next line of code in the batch leaving me with a 0KB .txt?

Comment: This is potentially a syntax error and your file isn't being written `/%HomeDrive%"Registered Owner"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your `findstr` command. `/c:"string"` is the way to indicate a search string parameter, and `c:` has no relation with any drive. See `findstr /?` for a complete reference of allowed switches.

For the wait, you have to wait **before** the `findstr`, waiting for finish of the process that generates the data.

Or, if the log is being generated with a redirection (`command > file.txt`) to the output file, then you can pipe the data to the `findstr`. Something like

```
whateverRetrivesData | findstr /i /v /c:"Registered Owner" > somewhere\file.txt
```

Comment: I corrected it and added the wait before, and now it works beautifully. Thank you!